# How do delete new lines in input?

Tags: python, arrays, input

The input for the code is supposed to be something like

```
10

1 0 1 0 1 0
```

and the output is supposed to be the absolute value difference of the number of 1s and 0s. The code works when I enter just the 2nd line but when I enter the first line the array is only [1, 0] so the output doesn't work either. How can I make it so both lines are registered?

```py
array = input()
array = array.replace(" ","")

array = [int(x) for x in str(array)]

one = (array.count(1))

zero = (array.count(0))

output = zero - one 

if output < 0:
    #output = output * -1

print(output)
```

Comment: Your `int(array)` does nothing as well as `str(array)` because `array` is already `str`. Calculate difference between amounts of `1` and `0` in string you can mush easier: `abs(sum(1 if c == "1" else -1 for c in array if c in "10"))`

Comment: What doesn't work? The output should be `0` if you enter `10` and this is what happens.

Comment: The input isn't 10, its 10, then a new line, then 1 0 1 0. But it only sees the input as 10, not 10 1 0 1 0.

Comment: You need to decide how the user will terminate their input then. If not newline, how? Basically, how should Python know the user has finished?

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, how can I do this?

Comment: Well I would first decide the way in which the user will signal the end of the input. Usually this is a newline character, but in your case thats clearly not going to work. So what do you want? Once you have decided (and probably edited the question to include this), then you are likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: how many lines is the input you want?

Comment: I only need 2 lines

Answer (score 0):

You want to take 2 lines of input from the user. But `input` always only reads 1 line. However, you may make 2 calls to `input`, one for each line, then join the two lines. E.g.

```
array = input()  # line 1
array += input() # line 2
```

The rest of your code could be written as follows:

```
array = array.replace(" ","")
array = [int(x) for x in array]

one = array.count(1)
zero = array.count(0)

output = zero - one 
print(output)
```

Comment: So, you're iterating over `array` at least 4 times which is quite inefficient when task could be solved with single iteration

Comment: I doubt a user will be able to type an input long enough for this to matter. As far as I see it, this is a toy programming problem, so lets just write it in the simplest way possible (and as close to the example given by OP) and worry about saving microseconds later.

Comment: @L.Grozinger, the problem is that method you advised is not the simplest. Not even simple.

Comment: @OlvinRoght feel free to edit with your suggestions or submit another answer.

Comment: @AdaÖzer if it worked, and *if* you think the answer will help others, please consider marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: @L.Grozinger, method `.count()` exists in all built-in sequences *(`str` is a sequence too)*, so if you want to apply it, you don't need to perform any modifications on `array`, just subtract count of `"0"` from count of `"1"` *(or vise versa)* and find [`abs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs): `output = abs(array.count("1") - array.count("0"))`

Comment: @OlvinRoght I think we misunderstand each other. The code I gave for the counting etc. was just written to closely resemble the OP's example code. Doubtless there are countless other (better) ways to do it.The actual question was about using `input`, and that's the focus of my answer. Again, feel free to edit!